# Stored procedure does not work with "allow multiple values" but direct query works in Visual Studio Reporting Services?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I am working on a simple report in Visual Studio 2010 where originally I have a direct query:

```
SELECT     
   DOCDATE, DOCID, CUSTNMBR, CUSTNAME, DOCAMNT
FROM         
   SOP30200
WHERE     
   (DOCDATE BETWEEN @Fromdate AND @Todate)
GROUP BY 
   DOCDATE, DOCID, CUSTNMBR, CUSTNAME, DOCAMNT
HAVING 
   (CUSTNAME = @Custname OR @Custname IS NULL) AND (DOCID IN (@DocID))
```

with the `DOCID` parameter set to "Allow multiple values" which works great.

However, when I create a stored procedure:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[Jae_EraSales]  
   @Custname nVARCHAR(MAX),
   @DocID nVARCHAR(50),
   @Fromdate datetime,
   @Todate datetime
as
   SELECT     
      DOCDATE, DOCID, CUSTNMBR, CUSTNAME, DOCAMNT
   FROM         
      SOP30200
   WHERE     
      (DOCDATE BETWEEN @Fromdate AND @Todate)
   GROUP BY 
       DOCDATE, DOCID, CUSTNMBR, CUSTNAME, DOCAMNT
   HAVING      
       (CUSTNAME = @Custname) AND (DOCID IN (@DocID))
GO
```

and use the stored procedure as my dataset...the SSRS report does not pull anything. It only pulls data with a single `DOCID` value.

Would anyone be able to explain why that is happening?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The answer to your question can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803231/tsql-in-not-working-properly-if-passed-as-parameter

Comment: Your stored procedure sees `DOCID IN 'test,hi,bye,foo,bar'` in which case there is not a single id with this string / int.  You really want `DOCID IN ('hi', 'bye', 'foo', 'bar')...` and to do that you need to write a function that returns a table of your in parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `IN` it looks at a set and not a single string expression. Because of this you need to implement a function such as CsvToInt to return a table.

`IN` expects an array not a variable, someone asked a very similar question which will definitely help you:  [tsql IN not working properly if passed as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803231/tsql-in-not-working-properly-if-passed-as-parameter)

The gist of it is simply writing a function that returns a table.

Comment: I'm guessing Visual Studio knows how to process the direct query to include the DOCID multiple values in a function. Thank you for the quick response JonH. That does explain my problem. =)

Comment: @JaeChang Yep VS translates this automatically, please accept the answer or close the question if this has helped you.